Main function with ES Modues in JavaScript
In NodeJS we can follow the convention of having a main method, and we can ensure the main method is only executed if the module was ran by the user, and not accessed from an import as follows:
function main(){
    console.log("This is the main method");
}

//Check was this ran by the user if so these two should match
if (require.main === module)
    main()

When using NodeJS with  type:"module" in the package.json, the JavaScript modules now expect ES syntax which means that require is not available. So what is the ES script standard for doing so, this information seems surprisingly hard to find.

here is a work around that I found, will not work with npm start, only with node xxx.js
if (import.meta.url === \file://${process.argv[1]}`) {
main();
}`

Thanks for the suggestion, surely there great folks at ECMA must have thought of a more elegant way?

did some poking around, this package seems to agree with you... basically the same as my previous code, except wrapped in fancy error handling and edge cases... 86 stars only so maybe not too reliable

this question deals with the same issue "The specification is a work in progress. So we don't know yet what the final code to retrieve this information looks like. – Walle Cyril"

It's an ES6 question, not a Python question. It asks for the ES6 module equivalent of a common pattern, a pattern found in python modules and commonjs modules (and elsewhere).

I don't agree. I would not think to type that when looking for an equivalent to the way CommonJS does it. Your assumptions are not forward thinking, that post was written 8 years ago, and its getting older every day, with several responses not even valid in 2023. This issue is all over SO and in the long run I think this maybe considered harmful.

People who are searching for "ES6 equivalent of commonjs module.main pattern" will find your question, and be directed to the single question where their problem is solved. SO will have worked as intended for them. If there are responses that don't work, downvote them (and comment why they're not valid if you want). That the question was asked 8 years ago doesn't change the answer in this case.

@bergi The problem is with downvoting. These responses may have been correct and well thought out within their historical context. So to vote people's well meaning answers down because the future has overtaken them would be cold and uncaring. We are compassionate humans with discretion, not robots blindly following rules and so replaceable soon by an algorithm. Also, it would take a lot of down votes,  not just mine to portray statistics that represent the current state of the art.
